# Caption width in xltabular environment

Tags: captions, line-breaking, xltabular

I am creating a Table as follows:

```
\usepackage{xltabular}
\begin{document}
\begin{xltabular}[l]{\textwidth}{X | X | X | X}
    \caption{Here is a long text that does not break and exceeds the page margin}
    \label{Table 1}
    Text 1  & Text 2  & Text 3 & Text 4  
\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

How can I force the caption to break according to \textwidth?

Thanks!

Comment: you are posting many many questions but still posting examples that can not be run. If you get an error ask about the error and show the exact error that you get and post  a test file that produces the error.

Answer (score 3):

In its current form, the code is not compilable, but intstead throws an error message

```
Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
```

The `xltabular` package internally indirectly loads the `longtable` package, which in turn makes the `\caption`  equivalent to `\multicolumn{n}{c}{\parbox{\LTcapwidth}{...}}`. Since the caption now is inside of a `\multicolumn` command spanning all columns of the table, it must be followed by a `\\`  to prevent the previously mentioned error message.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltabular}

\begin{document}


\begin{xltabular}[l]{\textwidth}{|X | X | X | X|}
    \caption{1 Here is a long text that does not break and exceeds the page margin  2 here is a long text that does not break and exceeds the page margin}
    \label{Table 1}  \\
    Text 1  & Text 2  & Text 3 & Text 4  
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

In order to make sure the captions of all `xltabular`s in your document take up the entire textwidth, you can add `\setlength{\LTcapwidth}{\linewidth}` to the preamble of your document.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\setlength{\LTcapwidth}{\linewidth} % make sure the caption takes up the whole linewidth

\begin{document}
        

\begin{xltabular}[l]{\textwidth}{|X | X | X | X|}
    \caption{1 Here is a long text that does not break and exceeds the page margin  2 here is a long text that does not break and exceeds the page margin}
    \label{Table 1}  \\
    Text 1  & Text 2  & Text 3 & Text 4  
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```